# How do I cause readers of a sqlite database to wait for a table to insert using pandas.DataFrame.to_sql()?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

In an attempt to reduce bandwidth issues on an internal webapp server querying a network database, I'm trying to cache this data on a timer to a SQLite database on the server itself to improve speed.

I am trying to refresh this table using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and their very handy DataFrame.to_sql(if_exists="replace") method. However, a simple test shows that when querying the table that is being "replaced" on a fast loop, it for a short while returns 0 rows rather than waiting for the to_sql insert to finish.

How can I force queries on that table to wait for it to be refreshed by pandas? Or is there another way I should be caching the network database tables locally to solve my problem?

Comment: sounds like you want to manage the data load.  In which case you'll need to manage state in a table or cache some where so that you know when an insert is being performed.

Comment: ah so like a switch to say whether that table is being updated? How would you recommend causing other queries to wait until that switch was off?

Comment: the easiest thing would be to check the status of the table or cache.  Where you the status value is something like, `ready` or `updating`.